Did the OKTA /authorize endpoint change? Before i got a 302, and now i'm getting a 200 OK
I've implemented around 2017 a process in .net, that invoked the OKTA /authorize endpoint, and would receive a 302 response. Afterwards, i would get the Location/AbsoluteUri, which would give me the Identity Provider URL that i would use to authenticate the user.
The code was implemented as:
private async Task<string> GetIdentityProviderUrl(WebFingerIdentityDto dto, string redirectUri, string state)
{
    var nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var idp = dto.links.First()?.properties?.oktaIdpId;

    var queryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"idp", idp},
        {"client_id", _clientId},
        {"response_type", "token id_token"},
        {"response_mode", "fragment"},
        {"state", state},
        {"nonce", nonce},
        {"scope", Scopes}
    };

    var url = $"{QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(AuthorizeUrl, queryParameters)}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}";

    using var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("okta");
    using var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    if (!HttpStatusCode.Found.Equals(response.StatusCode))
        throw new HttpResponseException(response.StatusCode, response.ToString());

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Headers.Location?.AbsoluteUri))
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Could not obtain Location Header.");

    var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Headers.Location?.AbsoluteUri);

    var error = queryParams.Get(ErrorKey);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, queryParams.Get(ErrorDescKey));

    return response.Headers.Location?.AbsoluteUri;
}

The authorize URL is something like:
https://dev-xxx.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?idp=0oahd5oxxxpVeVXXhe5d7&client_id=0oahxxxwvoGT8i3qW5d7&response_type=token%20id_token&response_mode=fragment&state=1111&nonce=15e7641d&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https://some-url.net/callback
We had a problem with our Okta server, so we had to configure a new Application in Okta, which we configured correctly.
BUT, as soon as we tried to login, the above code no longer return 302, but instead, it returns a 200 OK.
Any idea what can be the problem? Did the /authorize API changed, and the response is not the same as before?
This is causing us a lot of problems as our clients aren't being able to login.
Thank you in advance.

Have you tried to hit this URL from your browser?

I did, i also received a 200 OK.

did you check the response? is it maybe some JS doing redirection?

I did. The HttpClient is configured with AllowAutoRedirect = false, so there is no redirection. And in the response there's no Location Header. I really don't know what has changed in Okta's API's, and i can't also find any information regarding these changes.

@VSOS - I'm having the same issue. Did you even find a solution?

Sorry, i didn't. We had some testing environments that were created when we developed this functionality, and we reconfigured those with the new data. Once done, we got the 302 response that our process is expecting.
